# Find magnitude of b given magnitude of c=a+b and angle between c and b.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The parallelogram determined by vectors  and  has area 2sqrt(3). If the vector =+ makes an angle of π/3 with 2, and ||=6, then what is ||?

The problem is that I don't understand how to start, even using the cross product equation. Can anyone give me a hint on where to start?

Comment: The place to start is [this mathSE protocol article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) which will help you avoid negative reactions from mathSE reviewers.  Further, if you examine the specific questions that your posting is expected to answer, you will find that these are just the sort of questions that will assist you in attacking the problem.  For example, if the problem is from a book or class, there have to be theorems, previously solved problems or worked examples that are pertinent here.  What are they?

Comment: You have three equations namely $$\begin{align*} \tag {1}\  |a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2\ a \cdot b & = 36 \\ \tag {2} a \cdot b + |b|^2 & = 3 |b| \\ \tag {3} |a| |b| \sin \theta & = 2 \sqrt 3 \end{align*}$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b.$ If you vary $\theta$ I think the magnitude of $b$ will differ. Try playing around.

Comment: According to wolfram alpha $|b| = \frac {2} {3}.$ Here it is $:$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=systems+of+three+equations+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%22x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+2xyz+%3D+36%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%22y%5E2+%2B+xyz+%3D+3y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation3%22%7D+-%3E%22xy+%5Csqrt+%7B1+-+z%5E2%7D+%3D+2+%5Csqrt+%7B3%7D%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three equations namely $$\begin{align*} \tag {1}  |a|^2 + |b|^2 + 2\ a \cdot b & = 36 \\ \tag {2} a \cdot b + |b|^2 & = 3 |b| \\ \tag {3} |a| |b| \sin \theta & = 2 \sqrt 3 \end{align*}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b.$

Let $x = |a|, y = |b|$ and $z = \cos \theta.$ With this substitution the above three equations become

$$\begin{align*} \tag {4}  x^2 + y^2 + 2 xyz  & = 36 \\ \tag {5} y + xz & = 3 \\  \tag {6} xy \sqrt {1 - z^2} & = 2 \sqrt 3 \end{align*}$$

Since $x \neq 0$ it follows from $(5)$ that $z = \frac {3 - y} {x}.$ Putting the value of $z$ in $(4)$ we have $x^2 = y^2 - 6y + 36.$ Finally putting the value of $x^2$ and $z$ in $(6)$ we have $y = \frac {2 \sqrt {3}} {\sqrt {27}} = \frac {2} {3},$ which is what you wanted to compute.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the answer! However, I'm a little confused about how you got (2). Can you elaborate on how you got the equation?

Comment: @Rhys Ng$:$ Since $c = a + b$ makes an angle $\frac {\pi} {3}$ with $2b$ and hence with $b$ we have $$a \cdot b + |b|^2 = (a + b) \cdot b = c \cdot b = |c| |b| \cos \frac {\pi} {3} = 3 |b|$$ because by the given condition $|c| = 6$ and we know that $\cos \frac {\pi} {3} = \frac {1} {2}.$ Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

See image. By area of triangle formula, $\frac 12 |\mathbb b| (6) \sin \frac {\pi} 3 = \sqrt 3 \implies |\mathbb b| = \frac 23$

[image]